# ¿Cómo recupero los cambios hechos después de hacer "git commit" y después "git checkout"?

Tags: git, git-commit

Tenia un proyecto en el cual había trabajado un buen tiempo, realicé un `git add .`, luego un `git commit -am ""`.

Al realizar un `git push` me generó un error, realice un `git checkout` y perdí toda la versión

¿Alguien me podría decir cómo puedo recuperar esa información?

Comment: ¿Qué te dice `git status`?

Comment: te acordas del contenido de "me generó un error" ?

Comment: Es probable que se haya perdido la versión, por eso es recomendable hacer un tag de respaldo.

Comment: checkout descarta todo lo añadido con add, si es osx o alguna versión de linux podes ver si tenes el file history disponible (windows trae soporte pero por lo general está desactivado, en osx es aparte del time machine).  cuando hay errores o conflictos lo mejor es hacer un stash antes que un checkout. btw pregunto lo del error para que no te vuelva a pasar =)

Comment: Regresa a tu rama con el git checkout y despues haz un git status para ver que cambios existen.

Comment: Ya hiciste el commit probablemente tengas un Bracho head..... Dale git status

Comment: el error que me genero fue que el HEAD estaba desacoplado, voy a revisar lo de volver a la rama y generar un git status